# How to access member of a class of one branch of hierarchy using pointer of class from another branch?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, casting

```
              class A
              /     \
          class B1  class B2
```

All classes have only public members.

`Class A` is publicly inherited and contains virtual member functions and non-virtual member functions with default print(cout) statements, `class B1` and `class B2` has only non-virtual functions, with definition of the virtual functions from `class A`.

I want to know how to access all members of B2 using pointer of B1, which casting could be used.

For example:

```cpp
B2 obj_b2;
B1* b1_ptr=&obj_b2;

// Using b1_ptr, access all members of obj_b2
```

If yes, then whether this can be extended further into more deep branches like:

```
              class A
              /     \
          class B1  class B2
            /   \     /   \
       class C1 ...  ...  ...
```

(Accessing members of `class C1`, etc. from second branch)

---

EDIT 1:

Maybe this will help; this is the example that I have written:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
    virtual void v_f1(){
        cout<<"virtual A::v_f1()\n";
    }
    void f1(){
        cout<<"A::f1()\n";
    }
};
class B1 : public A{
public:
    virtual void v_f2(){
        cout<<"virtual B1::v_f2()\n";
    }
    void v_f1(){
        cout<<"A<-B1::v_f1()\n";
    }
    void f2(){
        cout<<"B1::f2()\n";
    }
};
class C1 : public B1{
public:
    void v_f2(){
        cout<<"B1<-C1::v_f2()\n";
    }
    void f3(){
        cout<<"C1::f3()\n";
    }
};
class D : public C1{
public:
    void f4(){
        cout<<"D::f4()\n";
    }
};
class B2 : public A{
public:
    void v_f(){
        cout<<"A<-B2::v_f()\n";
    }
    void f5(){
        cout<<"B2::f5()\n";
    }
};
class C2 : public B2{
public:
    void f6(){
        cout<<"C2::f6()\n";
    }
};
int main(){
    C2 c2_obj;
    C2* c2_obj_ref=&c2_obj;
    D* d_ptr = dynamic_cast<D*>(c2_obj_ref);

    // This statement gives segmentation fault,
    // if commented out, the code works fine.
    d_ptr->v_f();

    // These work fine
    d_ptr->f();
    dynamic_cast<C2*>(d_ptr)->f5();
    dynamic_cast<C2*>(d_ptr)->f6();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I came across `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast`, etc. in casting in C++. So, I wondered, if it's possible.

Comment: They explained why you can't in the answer, but you should understand you MUST NOT do something like that. It's a design flawless and will bring to you only pain and sufference

Answer (score 7):

An object of type `B1` does not have the members that `B2` declares.

If you try to treat an object as a type that it is not, your program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 4):

You basically can't.

B1 inherits from A, but know nothing from any other class the inherits from A.
You can upcast a B1 object to A or down cast A to a B1 objet. If you do both you'll eitehr have a bad cast exception or a null ptr (see comments)

What you are doing here is upcasting a B2 to A then downcasting an A to a B1 (if it compiles what I'm not sure of) so you may loose some B2 informations from the upcast that you can recollect in you downcast.

If you want to do this, you should rather wonder if B1 and B2 are basically the same class and should differ in a different way. For instance is say A is `Character`, B1 is `Soldier` and B2 is `Creature`, you could just have class A and inherited class `AInstance` with a private parameter `bool soldier` and `bool creature` that you can then use for printing or algorithm purposes.

Hope that helps !

Comment: "If it works" is *very* bad advice with C++. Undefined behaviour can *seem* to work until a seemingly unrelated change means it doesn't

Comment: That's absolutely right! I edited the post to rephrase it, it should match more what I meant.

Comment: when used right a `dynamic_cast` is neither unsafe nor impossible

Comment: Than I wonder what happends if you `dynamic_cast` the A-upcasted B2 to B1, would it run ?

Comment: i was refering to your wording rather than the question. Your first paragraph is only about up and down casting which is completely possible

Comment: @startresse depends if you `dynamic_cast<B1&>(ref)` or `dynamic_cast<B1*>(ptr)`, it will either throw `std::bad_cast` or be a null pointer